# grub2 equivalent of syslinux memdisk?

Tags: iso-image, grub

Since syslinux' memdisk have problems loading WinPE isos on UEFI, I am trying to try that with grub instead.

The problem is that I don't know how to boot directly from an iso inside grub, with the aditional problem that this grub is run on a PXE environment with TFTP.

I've tried

```
menuentry "Windows 7 Recovery Disc" {
loopback loop (tftp,<serverip>)/boot/iso/w7repairdisc-32bit.iso
set root=(loop)
chainloader (loop)
}
```

As I found somewhere, but I am getting a `invalid filename` error.

With syslinux and memdisk it was much easier... is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Which line gives the `invalid filename` error?

Answer (score 1):

Use memdisk in grub2:

```
linux16 /memdisk <type-for-iso> // I use for harddrives: "harddisk"
initrd16 <full-path-to-the-iso>
```

Copy the memdisk file on the boot partition where Grub2 is, or edit the path to memdisk on first line.

Grub2 can directly load memdisk... if with memdisk it was working for you, why not still use memdisk?

Comment: Does `full-path-to-the-iso` include `/boot`?